# How do I make Svelte update input components like React does?

Tags: reactive-programming, svelte, svelte-3

I'm looking to sanitise user input on the fly. Consider [this Svelte REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/84c18491f99c4624a074d43b98ce3d27?version=3.23.2) where we attempt to remove all x's that the user types. If you type an "x", the sanitised version is the same as the original, so it doesn't update, but the "x" is still displayed in the input field. Once you type another character, there *is* a change, so the field is updated with the "x" removed. Compare this to [this React sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-repl-ru4vr?file=/src/index.js) where the state is always properly reflected.

**How do I get React's behaviour in Svelte?**

One could technically work around this issue by writing to `value` in the toy example (e.g. by having a two-way binding instead: `bind:value={value}`). That would cause Svelte to update `value` twice, first with the wrong value which then *does* trigger the invalidation code and then a second time with the right value. In the scenario I'm dealing with, I'm reading from an Observable which are read-only, so that hack is not an option. You can play around with such an example [in this Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/e0c3abac334f4c798e8999a3262f6969?version=3.23.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use beforeinput event:

```
<script>
    let value = 'test';

    function sanitize(e) {
        if (e.data.includes('x')) e.preventDefault();
    }
</script>

<input
    value={value}
    on:beforeinput={sanitize}
/>
```

[Demo](https://svelte.dev/repl/51781e72693547dcb859b42de197a404?version=3.23.2)

You can actually use the same pattern for any input to get behavior like in react, here is [the example of controlled input](https://svelte.dev/repl/ac0c53c69fbc4b78adf39c901fe63dda?version=3.52.0)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the event's default behaviour:

```html
<script>
  let value = 'test';

  function sanitize(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    value = e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/x/g, '');
  }
</script>

<input
  value={value}
  on:input={sanitize}
/>
```

[Demo here](https://svelte.dev/repl/cfbe400a07a14d63ad806734dcf99b4b?version=3.23.2).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Rich. I'm afraid that doesn't help.
1) the `input` event is not a cancelable event, so `preventDefault` does nothing here. (You might be confusing with `keypress`?)
2) The `value = e.target.value` part is what causes the invalidation here, which I explicitly stated I didn't want since I'm dealing with an Observable in my real case.
Thank you though!

Comment: Did you try the linked REPL demo? I assure you the `input` event is cancelable! And if the problem you're trying to solve relates to an Observable, include that in the provided repro and code sample, otherwise I'm not sure how much help people are going to be able to give you.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've updated the question. I hope it's more clear now.

I did try the REPL demo. You can observe that the `preventDefault` here doesn't achieve its goal by removing the `value = e.target.value` from your example. I'm not sure if you were referring to something Svelte does on top of the normal event processing, but the normal `input` event in the web standards is most certainly not cancelable. (See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event).)

Thank you for thinking this through with me!

Comment: @RichHarris This works, but why isn't it enough to assign the sanitized input to the value variable? Is this a bug?