# Svelte - Input value doesn't always update

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I'm trying to create an input component in Svelte where the value is updated by a JavaScript function. However, if the new value is the same as the old value, Svelte will not update the input element.

For instance, this component should restrict input to only numbers. If you were to type "123abc", the input will then display "123abc" while the `value` variable is just "123".

```
<script>
    let value = ''
    
    const handleInput = (event) => {
        value = event.currentTarget.value.replace(/[^\d]/gu, '')
    }
</script>

<input {value} type='text' on:input={handleInput} />

<p>
    Value: "{value}"
</p>
```

Is there way to always make the input value to equal the `value` variable?

#### Attempted solutions

- Use the HTML `pattern` attribute. While it works for this example, it will not work for the general case I'm trying to solve
- Could just say `event.currentTarget.value = value`. This works perfectly, but it doesn't seem Svelte-like.
- `bind:value` has the same issues as the event listener (e.g., `$: value = value.replace(/[^\d]/gu, '')`). Also, in the general case, `bind:value` won't work for me as I'm comparing the previous and updated value.

Related

- [How do I make Svelte update input components like React does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62426548/how-do-i-make-svelte-update-input-components-like-react-does)

Comment: I know it's been a while, but I am curious to know why don't you use `<input type="number"/>` I know you won't be able to display the strings, but I don't think it is that important since it won't be used as value anyways,

Comment: There's only two differences between `type="text"` and `type="number"`: 1) mobile devices will use the numeric keyboard, 2) desktop devices will display the increment/decrement arrows. I believe best practice for choosing between the two is: want the increment/decrement arrows? Choose `type="number"`. Else, restrict the acceptable characters and set the mobile keyboard. I could be wrong, but that's my thought process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with doing `event.currentTarget.value = value` it might not *seem* Svelte like but it's perfectly acceptable.

Comment: It works, but why is it necessary? Is there a principle of Svelte reactivity that would allow us to predict that setting the value variable in the handleInput function would not update the value property of the input? Or is this simply a bug in Svelte?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you have not used `bind:value` and declares the `value` to its input but instead, you could use this method

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/704ab2aa554b4ce1bd66bf036d1062f3?version=3.38.2)

```html
<script>
    let value = ''
    
    $: sanitized = value.replace(/[^\d]/gu, '')
</script>


<input bind:value />

<p>
    display value: {value}
</p>

<p>
    display value: {sanitized}
</p>
```

Comment: This still has the same issue, though. You're can still type letters into the input. Yes, the sanitized value won't have those letters, but the input will still display them. Didn't mention this in the question (so I'll update it), but I also need to use the event listener in this case and not `bind:value`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to update `event.currentTarget.value` directly, this will also work.

```js
const handleInput = (event) => {
    value = event.currentTarget.value;
    value = value.replace(/[^\d]/gu, '');
}
```